# Como criar hierarquia de componentes com React Native?

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, componentes

Quero criar componentes com o TextInput, sendo que o padrão é o meu componente de Input sem máscara, e os filhos terão máscara ou alguma outra tratativa.

Tenho atualmente o Input padrão que contém apenas os estilos e retornam o texto cru ao digitar. Também tenho um Input com máscara de CPF / CNPJ, e na hora de exportar estou usando um arquivo index.js que apenas contém esses dois componentes e os exporta.

*index.js*

```
import Input from './Input'
import CpfCnpj from './input-masks/InputCpfCnpj'

export { CpfCnpj }

export default Input
```

Porém gostaria de utilizar dessa forma quando quiser usar sem máscaras:

```
<Input {...this.props} />
```

E assim quando precisar de alguma máscara:

```
<Input.CpfCnpj {...this.props} />
```

---

Uma maneira que encontrei foi fazer isso no arquivo *index.js*

```
import Input from './Input'
import CpfCnpj from './input-masks/InputCpfCnpj'

Input.CpfCnpj = CpfCnpj

export default Input
```

Gostaria de saber se existe outra forma, e se essa é uma boa prática?

Answer (score 1):

Há duas formas que conheço de um componente "herdar" as propriedades de outro, que é estendo ou colocando dentro de outro.

### HERANÇA

**Componente "pai":**

```
import React from 'react';

class GenericForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onChange = e => {
    const target = e.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    this.setState({
      dataForm: { ...this.state.dataForm, [e.target.name]: value}
    });
  }
}
export default GenericForm;
```

**Componente filho:**

```
class FormLogin extends GenericForm {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: {
        login: '',
        password: ''
      },
      loading: false,
      errors: {}
    };
  }
}
```

### COMPONENTE DENTRO DE COMPONENTE

**Tabela genérica** (apenas estilo)

```
class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table className={`${this.props.className} Table`}>
        {this.props.children}
      </table>
    )
  }
}
```

**Tabela Específica:** aqui pode ser adicionado mais estilos, métodos e outros

```
class TableList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  open() {
    // do something
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Table className={`${this.props.className} TableList` onClick={this.open}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Table>
    )
  }
}
```

Assim, quando eu renderizar "TableList" renderizarei também "Table".

```
<TableList className="alunos-disponiveis">
  <tr>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Endereço de Partida</th>
    <th>Endereço de Regresso</th>
  </tr>
  {
    data.passengerList.map(item => (
      <tr>
        <td>{item.name}</td>
        <td>{item.localeStart.address}</td>
        <td>{item.localeFinish.address}</td>
      </tr>
    ))
  }
</TableList>
```

Comment: Herança entre componentes não é recomendado. Composição seria uma melhor solução para isso, veja: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html